# Macbook Pro Early 2011 15 inch, Mountain Lion Booting issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, recovery

My Macbook Pro is not booting normally. I tried many options but no success. If I try to recovery mode or try to boot from USB, a blue screen appears. So I can't do fresh install. I checked hardware test, it says ok, I used the disk in target disk mode in my another macbook pro and it runs on there. Only in this machine the problem is occurring.

Youtube Video about the problem: http://youtu.be/mBk-qcvktPs

If you know the solution help me please.

Spec: 
MacBook Pro, Intel Core i7 
Processor Speed: 2 GHz

Memory: 8GB

Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M
VRAM: 256 MB

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: That's a very strange issue. Have you tried the typical SMC and PRAM reset? Judging that you're running on a relatively new i7 chip, is there a chance you can take in to an Apple store? Generally problems persisting regardless of boot drive are caused by a hardware problem. Try taking out one RAM module (booting with just one) and then replacing it to isolate the other. That can help eliminate suspicion of a memory issue.

Comment: The problem happened 2nd time. Somedays ago when it first occurred, I took it to nearby Apple authorised service centre. After 3 days they fix it and noted just format the disk and re-installed lion, there is no hardware problem.  But after 3 days again the same problem occurred. I changed RAM as you said but the issue isn't solving. And I did PRAM, and disconnected Battery for sometimes. But unsuccessful.

Comment: Hmm that's really strange. It'd be hard to narrow down the problem. I would usually diagnose these problems with my copy of Apple's Service Diagnostics (thank you Pirate Bay) which gives very low level information on the performance of the machine. I really don't know what could be wrong in this case =/

Comment: Thanks @XAleXOwnZX for your kind information and advice. I started downloading from (pirate bay) after I got the app I'll test again.

Comment: I downloaded Apple Service Diagnostics, and I'm able to do EFI test, no hardware problem, all test passed. Then I tried to boot via OS Test. After I select it a loading icon occurs and at last the white screen shows. The same white screen shows in normal boot up, recovery boot up. If I try safe mode then instead of white screen a blue screen shows.

Comment: Wow =/ I've got nothin

Comment: Can you boot from optical media such as an OS X disk or Ubuntu Live CD?

Comment: No, I can't boot, and somedays ago I sent it to Authorised Service repair shop in here, and finally they said, logic board may be spoiled. So If I want to fix it, I've to purchase a new logic board. So I decided not to fix this laptop. I used this laptop 2 years, so better buy new one.

Comment: Did you find the problem? I am getting same blu screen and can't make OS X 10.8.3 pass beyond that screen. I have tried booting via external usb and also via teh recovery disk and nothing helps.

Comment: Have you tried starting up the macbook in verbose mode? Press Command + V immediately after powering up the macbook. The Diagnostic output might help you to pin-down the actual problem. It might be a 3rd party kernel extensions or something that's keeping your mac from booting.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I have tried resetting SMC, PRAM, running Disk Utility (from single user mode), nothing works...and then randomly it will boot correctly. I think it may be graphics card related, I am wondering if there is a way to disable the AMD graphics card so the macbook is foreces to use the intel...but I supposed safemode would do that?

Comment: it describes symptoms that I also have - included ones shown in your youtube video: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4766577?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

From the tests you made we can eliminate a list of potential culprit
candidates:

1. memory: hardware tests
2. internal disk: use in target mode
   but you might be tougher on this test:
   in target disk mode fire `Disk Utility` and perform some (ex.: 4)
   `Verify disk` one after the other.
3. OS: re-install by an Apple service center

Here are the remaining candidates:

1. motherboard
2. graphical cards

## Receipe to kill other culprit candidates

If your problem is just due to a graphical chain problem, your
system might be correctly booted, but you can't notice
    it. To check this probability, you will have to set your Mac
    so as to be able to remotely verify that it is alive or dead.

- Connect the bad Mac to a good one with an Ethernet cable,
- Boot the culprit Mac, even if it does just show you his blue screen,
- Open a `Terminal` on good Mac, and get the broadcasting IP address.
  The following command will display it:

  ```
      ifconfig en0
  ```

  behind the keyword `broadcast` (3rd line).
  You may also get it at first with a slightly more tricky command:

  ```
     ifconfig en0 | sed -n 's,^.*broadcast \(.*\)$,\1,p'
  ```

  Let's say that it is `broacast_IP` (most probably it will be `169.254.255.255`).
- do a ping broadcast to see how many Mac are alive:

  ```
      ping broadcast_IP
  ```

  if this command reply you with 2 different IP addresses, then you can
  conclude that bad Mac is alive and its graphical chain is dead.

  On the other hand, if you only get a reply of your good Mac,
  then bad Mac is really dead, and the last culprit is the good
  (i.e. motherboard).